# Python request futures does not seem to be working for me

Tags: python, python-requests, concurrent.futures

I have the following piece of code

```
import concurrent.futures as cf
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession

urls = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'https://foursquare.com/'] * 500

futures = []
session = FuturesSession(executor=cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8))

for url in urls:
    futures.append(session.get(url))

for future in cf.as_completed(futures):
    result = len(future.result().content)
    print(result)
```

However this code errors out using a message like

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))

When the length of url list is about 300 it works

but when i have about 500 urls i am back to the same weird error

The complete stack trace is like

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConnectionResetError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\python36\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redi
rect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601

c:\python36\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked
, **httplib_request_kw)
    385                     # otherwise it looks like a programming error was the cause.
--> 386                     six.raise_from(e, None)
    387         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:

c:\python36\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

c:\python36\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked
, **httplib_request_kw)
    381                 try:
--> 382                     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
    383                 except Exception as e:

c:\python36\lib\http\client.py in getresponse(self)
   1330             try:
-> 1331                 response.begin()
   1332             except ConnectionError:

c:\python36\lib\http\client.py in begin(self)
    296         while True:
--> 297             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    298             if status != CONTINUE:

c:\python36\lib\http\client.py in _read_status(self)
    257     def _read_status(self):
--> 258         line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
    259         if len(line) > _MAXLINE:

c:\python36\lib\socket.py in readinto(self, b)
    585             try:
--> 586                 return self._sock.recv_into(b)
    587             except timeout:

c:\python36\lib\ssl.py in recv_into(self, buffer, nbytes, flags)
   1001                   self.__class__)
-> 1002             return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
   1003         else:

c:\python36\lib\ssl.py in read(self, len, buffer)
    864         try:
--> 865             return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    866         except SSLError as x:

c:\python36\lib\ssl.py in read(self, len, buffer)
    624         if buffer is not None:
--> 625             v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    626         else:

ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\python36\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    422                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 423                     timeout=timeout
    424                 )

c:\python36\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redi
rect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    648             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
--> 649                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    650             retries.sleep()

c:\python36\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stack
trace)
    346             if read is False or not self._is_method_retryable(method):
--> 347                 raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
    348             elif read is not None:

c:\python36\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    684         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 685             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    686         raise value

c:\python36\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redi
rect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601

c:\python36\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked
, **httplib_request_kw)
    385                     # otherwise it looks like a programming error was the cause.
--> 386                     six.raise_from(e, None)
    387         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:

c:\python36\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

c:\python36\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked
, **httplib_request_kw)
    381                 try:
--> 382                     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
    383                 except Exception as e:

c:\python36\lib\http\client.py in getresponse(self)
   1330             try:
-> 1331                 response.begin()
   1332             except ConnectionError:

c:\python36\lib\http\client.py in begin(self)
    296         while True:
--> 297             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    298             if status != CONTINUE:

c:\python36\lib\http\client.py in _read_status(self)
    257     def _read_status(self):
--> 258         line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
    259         if len(line) > _MAXLINE:

c:\python36\lib\socket.py in readinto(self, b)
    585             try:
--> 586                 return self._sock.recv_into(b)
    587             except timeout:

c:\python36\lib\ssl.py in recv_into(self, buffer, nbytes, flags)
   1001                   self.__class__)
-> 1002             return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
   1003         else:

c:\python36\lib\ssl.py in read(self, len, buffer)
    864         try:
--> 865             return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    866         except SSLError as x:

c:\python36\lib\ssl.py in read(self, len, buffer)
    624         if buffer is not None:
--> 625             v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    626         else:

ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host',
None, 10054, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-144-e24ea43223c2> in <module>()
     15
     16 for idx,future in enumerate(cf.as_completed(futures)):
---> 17     result = len(future.result().content)
     18     print(idx,result)
     19

c:\python36\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    396                 raise CancelledError()
    397             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 398                 return self.__get_result()
    399
    400             self._condition.wait(timeout)

c:\python36\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in __get_result(self)
    355     def __get_result(self):
    356         if self._exception:
--> 357             raise self._exception
    358         else:
    359             return self._result

c:\python36\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py in run(self)
     53
     54         try:
---> 55             result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
     56         except BaseException as e:
     57             self.future.set_exception(e)

c:\python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeou
t, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    486         }
    487         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 488         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    489
    490         return resp

c:\python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    607
    608         # Send the request
--> 609         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    610
    611         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

c:\python36\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    471
    472         except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
--> 473             raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
    474
    475         except MaxRetryError as e:

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'
, None, 10054, None))

In [145]:
```

Comment: Does it work with fewer than 2500 requests?  Scale it down to 2 and work up.

Comment: John brilliant i followed your advice and made some changes its weird but it works not sure why though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your sites, they limit the number of connections from an IP because of things like DOS attacks (Not an expert).

As you can see in the error `ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

Comment: Interesting Reza what i did was removed requests_futures and used the synchronous request library and concurrent futures thread pool executor and that library even though much slower does not give this error

Comment: @user3249433 Sites limit the rate of requests, not just their number. With 8 worker threads, you’re hitting every one of those sites 8 times more often than with 1 thread.

Comment: @user3249433 that's because it's slower. You can't go above a certain number of requests for each sites per seconds.